# Using AppleScript to select dropdown menu item containing string

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

The following code selects the menu item of a dropdown displaying the string `Mac mini Speakers`:

```
click (menu item "Mac mini Speakers") of menu 1 of popupButton
```

But I want to select the menu item by *substring*. In my use case I don't know the full name. So something like this (but this does **not** work):

```
click (menu item where value contains "Speakers") of menu 1 of popupButton
```

How can I specify a menu item by a substring of the content displayed in the menu item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing under **macOS Catalina** in **Script Editor** with **System Preferences** > **Sound** > **Sound Effects** opened, the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* clicks the **MacBook Pro Speakers** *menu item* for the **Play sound effects through:** *pop-up menu*:

```applescript
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "System Preferences"
        click pop up button 1 of tab group 1 of window 1
        delay 0.25
        tell tab group 1 of window 1
            click (menu items of menu 1 of pop up button 1 ¬
                whose name contains "Speakers")
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```